# jQuery Replace Second Space of Sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace second space occurrence of the sentence with a br.

I have tried this but it is deleting the rest.

```
var title = "My Title Needs Brace".split(" ").slice(0, 2).join(" ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var title = "My Title Needs Brace".split(" ");

title.forEach(function(item, i, title){
  if(i==1)
    title[i] += "<br/>";
  else
  title[i] += ' ';
})

console.log(title.join(''));
```

Answer (score 4):

### That will do the trick:

```
"My Title Needs Brace"
   .split(' ')
   .reduce(function (str, part, i) {
      return str + (i === 2 ? '<br/>' : ' ') + part
   });

// "My Title<br/>Needs Brace"
```

### Let's break it and see how it works:

First, we take the string and **split** it. we'll use `" "` as our separator

```
"My Title Needs Brace".split(' ')

// ["My", "Title", "Needs", "Brace"]
```

Second, we'll use **reduce** to combine the array back into one string

```
["My", "Title", "Needs", "Brace"]
   .reduce(function (str, part) { return str + ' ' + part }, '');

// "My Title Needs Brace"
```

Why **reduce** and not **join**?
The advantage of reduce over join is that it allows us to use a function, which will give us a fine-grained control over how we join back each part of the string

Now, all that left is to replace the 2nd space with `<br/>`,
for that, we'll use the 3rd argument of the reduce function, which stands for the index, and ask:

is this the 3rd part? use `<br/>`
otherwise, use `" "`

```
"My Title Needs Brace"
   .split(' ')
   .reduce(function (str, part, i) {
      return str + (i === 2 ? '<br/>' : ' ') + part
   });

// "My Title<br/>Needs Brace"
```

Note that this is the index of the string "part", not the spaces between them so the index is 2, not 1.

### More about:

- [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to replace second space occurrence of the sentence with a br.

The simple way to do that is to add `"<br/>"` to the second element.

Here is the Code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var title = "My Title Needs Brace".split(" ");
  title[1] = title[1]+"<br/>";
  var newstr = title.join(" ");
  $("#textd").html(newstr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textd">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***maybe that will help :***

```
var title = "My Title Needs Brace".split(" ");
t1=title [0]; My
t2=title[1]; // Title 
t3=title[2]; // Needs 
t4=title[3]; // Brace
```

**you can drew here anything :**

```
var htmlString = '' + t1 +''+ t2 + '<br />' +  t3 +''+ t4 + '';
$('Anywhere').append(htmlString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without splitting the string:

```
var title = 'My Title Needs Brace'.replace(/( .*?) /, '$1<br>');
```

Here, [`String.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) takes a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and a string as arguments. The regex matches everything from the first space up through the second space, keeping everything except the second space in a [capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references). The string [replaces the entire match with the contents of the capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), followed by `'<br>'`. Since the capturing group doesn't include the second space, this effectively only replaces the second space.